# QGIS fails to recognize Geometry Column in SQL Server

Tags: qgis, sql, geometry

I have a table `[stg].[Stops]` in SQL Server that stores a variety of fields including a `well-known binary`, the `GEOM` column, that has been created from the `stop_lat` and `stop_lon` fields. The `GEOM` is a `geometry` data type. Here is a screenshot of the table.

[image]

However, when I go into QGIS and attempt to add the SQL Server table. QGIS does not recognize the table in the [stg] Schema.

[image]

What am I missing here? I do not have a geometry_columns table, but I don't think thats the issue.

Comment: do you have "geometry_columns" table in dbo schema ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL server but in PostGIS there is a Populate_Geometry_Columns command to, well, populate the geometry columns.